Large outdoor jasmine dying
Jasmine vine suddenly dying
My very large, very established jasmine started wilting and dying. I pruned the original dying areas but now all of it is dying . It is outdoors growing over a pergola. One side died first, now the entire plant is dying . Plant is over 7’ tall, 3’ in diameter,with vines spreading 7’.

How is it dying?  Can you give us a picture of the leaves to show if/how they are discolouring/curling?

And your location please!  Has it been wet and cool where you are?
